# For a simple sequence detector, is there a problem with the FSM diagram for unused states?

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines, sequence-detector

This is the diagram, and the sequence we are detecting is 1011. The problem did not specify whether it is Mealy or Moore FSM, or whether it is overlapping or non-overlapping.

[image]

When we get an input of 0, the sequence would be 10110. If it is an overlapping case, then the last sequence would be 10 (10110), and it is supposed to go to the C state as C has 10 of the sequence. If it is non-overlapping, then the E state will directly go to the initial state A (for input 0 and 1).

For the not-used state, there is no saying that all unused goes to 0.  But this is how the slide is shown, and I think it is wrong for the non-overlapping case.  I am not confident with the overlapping case.

[image]

```
101 = if input gets 0, then it is supposed to go to C state (10). For 1, B state
110 = for input 0, A state. For input 1, B state
111 = for input 0, C state. For input 1, A state.
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I don't usually show unused states in the state diagram.  In language-based design tool (usually VHDL or Verilog) there's something like an "OTHERS" clause that picks up all the unused states and has them transition to one of the known states.

Comment: OT: Why do you think the detected sequence is 10110? The output is 1 after 1011 and each next bit outputs 0 again.

Answer (score 1):

The top diagram indicates that the state machine was encoded using a 3-bit state vector.  This means that there are 8 possible states.  Since only 5 states are used for normal sequence detection (A-E), this leaves 3 unused states (F-H).

The diagram pessimistically assumes that it is not known how any of the unused states was entered.  For example, if we entered state F, there is no way to know what the previous state was.  Since the diagram shows no transition arcs into any unused state, we could assume the only way to get there was via a [soft error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_error).

Furthermore, since the diagram shows no way out of an unused state, we can assume the implementation requires a hardware reset to get out of that state and back into a used state (presumably state A).

The diagram isn't wrong.  It implies a specific hardware implementation.